# Using value_counts with False/True. How to get false/true = 0 when there is any false or true

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing an application that generates a report. One part of the output shows how many matches are between two columns (match = True, no match = False). In order to do that I use `df.column.value_counts()` which output is

```
False    2
True     1
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

So I was thinking to show the result in the report something like

```
# This is a simplify example
print(" Position with same genotype: ", df.column.value_counts()[1])
print(" Position with different genotype: ", df.column.value_counts()[0])
```

I have noticed that the order of this output change depending on what False or True is found first in the table ( I think I can solve this with sort ). However, another bigger concern I am thinking of is if there is no False or non True are found in the table the output is:

```
# For example not Falses
True     3
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

I was expected this:

```
# For example not Falses
True     3
False    0
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

How can I solve this to avoid future errors? It is quite unlike that happen, it is going to be at least one false or true but I want to be sure that not error happens as this application is going to be run many times with different samples so theoretically  this situation can happen.

Comment: what do you mean with 'no False or non True' values, what are the other options that occur in your df?

Comment: @flyinthelotion i think he means if there are only true values found, which he can solve by checking the length of the list. If it is only 1 then you are missing one of the values and that can be handled

Comment: @flyinthelotion When the application run, three situations can happen: First True and False are found in the column, second only True are found third only False are found. 
@ Sean Powell thanks that could be one solution, the thing is to find the way that I could know what are the missing value to be able to return for example True = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of working with this, I have found an additional way to do this not explained yet

```
# This column has hom and het values only
df['Hom/het'].value_counts()["hom"] 
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`Series.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html)

We can use the `get` method of the pandas series and specify the default value as `0`

```
s = df['column'].value_counts()

print("Position with same genotype: ", s.get(True, 0))
print("Position with different genotype: ", s.get(False, 0))
```

Result

```
Position with same genotype:  2
Position with different genotype:  1
```

Comment: Let's me have a look at this approach, I will come back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with both `True` and `False` (i.e. `[False, True]`) and [`fillna(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to get the result always the fixed sequence (`False` then `True`) and also with default value 0 even if absent:

```
df['column'].value_counts().reindex([False, True]).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Demo:

```
val_count = df['column'].value_counts().reindex([False, True]).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(" Position with same genotype: ", val_count[1])
print(" Position with different genotype: ", val_count[0])
```

Output:

```
Position with same genotype:  1
Position with different genotype:  2
```